# A generic script for checking the health of application

Tags: shell

I have written one shell script (Health_app.sh) which checks the health of the application. And for that it takes the name of the processes from App_Details file and checks for PID (whether it is running or not) and if it is not running and grep for that process in logs (field 3) and send email to the email id mentioned in the App_Details file (field 4).

App_Details is having records like:

> process_Name|Process_description|logfile_path|email
>
> abcd|main proceess to invoke the
>   dataready|/123/456/log|vikas@yahoo.com
>
> pqrs|2nd
>   process..........................|/123/456/log|vikas@yahoo.com

Here is how my script looks like:

```
  export App_Details=/home/123/sanity/App_Details

  while read line
  do
      export procname=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f1)
      export PROCDES=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f2)
      #if ps -ef |grep [`echo $procname|awk '{print substr($0,1,1)}'`] [`echo $procname|awk '{print substr($0,2,length($0))}'`]> /dev/null
      if ps -ef |grep -q [`echo $procname|awk '{print substr($0,1,1)}'`] `echo $procname|awk '{print substr($0,2,length($0))}'`

      then
          export part1=[`echo $procname|awk '{print substr($0,1,1)}'`]
          export part2=`echo $procname|awk '{print substr($0,2,length($0))}'`
          export PROCID=`ps -ef |grep $part1$part2|awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'`
      else
          export PROCID="OFFLINE"
          trace_path=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f3)
          export mail=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f4)
          file_name=`ls -rt $trace_path/$procname*.trc 2>/dev/null | tail -1`
        #export PROCDES=$(echo `tail -10 $file_name`)
        (echo `tail -10 $file_name`) >> send.txt
        mailx -s "Please find the alerts for your application OFFLINE services" vikas@domain.com < send.txt
      fi
      echo $PROCID|awk '{ printf("%-20s", $0)}'
      echo $procname|awk '{ printf("%-20s", $0)}'
      echo $PROCDES|awk '{ printf("%-20s\n", $0)}'
  done<$App_Details
```

Now the issue is that `grep -q` is illegal for solaris and it is not working in solaris server.

Comment: So don't use `-q`.  Just redirect stdout and stderr for the grep command to `/dev/null` if you don't want to see it.